# Render is not always the same

Tags: html, css

I might be going pixel-crazy, but when I'm working on front-end design, I like things to be accurate.
Let's say I have 3 squares in a container element, with exactly the same HTML markup:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
</div>
```

They all have the same style. The one of the middle is not the exactly same than the others. It misses some padding pixels on the sides.

Can someone tell me why? Is there a way to make it work?
I encounter the problem on Chrome (last version). On Firefox, none of them are alike. It's a shame but it only works as expected on IE11.

Code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytLrdk26/1/)):

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

.navigator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid #3cbeff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.page>div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.page>div.active {
  animation-name: active;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes active {
  from {
    background-color: #3cbeff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I got on my screen. For Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

With @KarelIG solution ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytLrdk26/2/)):

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

.navigator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid #3cbeff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.page>div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.page>div.active {
  animation-name: active;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes active {
  from {
    background-color: #3cbeff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got this:

[image: KareIG solution on Chrome]

To me, the first square is slightly different from the others. On the two others, the side padding is `1px` less than the top/bottom padding.

**EDIT**

It is definitely a subpixel rendering problem.

I guess I cannot help it: even if everything is in px in my CSS, I obviously have to center one element or another, and I cannot guarantee it'll fit every hardware pixel grid.

I saw that it was the problem by moving the squares: according to their position and margin between each other, the square would change and eventually not be square.

I assume I should just let it go as it is! Except if someone has another idea, but I didn't find any clean solution that will work for every browser to solve that kind of problem so far.

Comment: They look all the same for me on Google chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome and your fiddle shows three perfectly equal squares

Comment: Uhm... checked your fiddle in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE. I quickly swapped between those browsers and couldn't find any difference. It shows what the CSS rules are describing.

Comment: I just edited the question with what I am seeing on my screen. But if it is just on my screen, maybe it's not very important... But still, I wonder why do I get that render :(

Comment: They look slightly different to me in Chrome but only if zoom is not 100%.

Comment: I thought it was due to the zoom too, but my Chrome was set to 100% when I did the screenshot...

Comment: Aah got the difference. I've played with the zoom level and I _did_ find the differences.

Comment: How does it look like when u see it with jsfiddle?

Comment: Probably nearly no one will ever pay attention to those missing pixels, but this feels really odd to do three times the same thing and not getting the same result each time! (I've added what I got for Firefox, also default zoom 100%)

Comment: just remove `box-sizing: border-box;` and use `padding: 0.2em` instead. Would do the thing.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it's still slightly different when it renders on my screen (I edited my post with a screenshot). I assume it's not really important and it basically depends from the resolution and the graphical rendering, from one computer to another...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Safari on iOS looks ok

Comment: I've found the problem on Chromium

Comment: I think this is related to subpixels issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676263/sub-pixels-calculated-and-rendered-differently-among-browsers I suppose the only way I have is to implement it another way... without any padding/margin