# CSS and rem: changing the html font-size creates inconsistent dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am using rems across all my project to calculate both font sizes and elements dimentions. The base html font-size used to be set at 10px. When I changed to 11 for design reasons, I noticed that a repeated line of .2rem height was not displayed consistently. Here is a codepen that can reproduce the issue:  https://codepen.io/jalef/pen/djeoxK . If the html font-size is changed from 10 to 11 the same thing happens.

```
html {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.line {
  height: .2rem;
  width: 50rem;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

*The consistent .2rem height lines that are produced when html font-size is set to 10px:*
[image: html font-size equal to 10px : consistent .2rem height line]

*The inconsistent .2rem height lines that are produced when html font-size is set to 11px:*
[image: html font-size equal to 11px : inconsistent .2rem height line]

Is there a reason why this is happening and is there a way to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676263/sub-pixels-calculated-and-rendered-differently-among-browsers

Answer (score -1):

It might be that there are some browser rendering issues.

You can try to use a border instead of the height of div.

Example:

```
border-bottom: 0.2rem solid purple;
```

[image]

Comment: Your border-bottom solution, has the same issues as the initial question, when you scale the font-size above 11px. I suppose it's an render issue, as you suggested. check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676263/sub-pixels-calculated-and-rendered-differently-among-browsers

Comment: 20px on my screen looks good. Make sure to delete the background-color line.

Comment: Any multiple of 5 results in a "good" line, as this would result in whole pixels.

Comment: So technically, you can go above 11px, just need to make sure it's a round number.