# Gap Between Divs?

Tags: html, css

Here I have two divs inside another div, the only problem is the white gap that is created between them.

```css
.box{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.it1,.it2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.it1{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.it2{
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="it1"></div>
    <div class="it2"></div>
</div>
```

[image: How it looks...]
[image: How I want it to look...]

Maybe I'm just being picky or it could even be my OCD but I really need to know if I'm just doing something wrong. I could make the boarder bigger but that is just feels like a workaround.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The snippet shows it working as expected. What browser are you using?

Comment: @disinfor Opera

Comment: Just as a note, using Chrome, I sometimes do see a white gap, but it appears and disappears when I mess around with the zoom function on the page.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as SolarBear, possibly a single-pixel difference when scaling the divs up where outer box is rounded up and inner boxes are rounded down?

Comment: Does your CSS have a CSS reset as well? That might help. At least `* { margin:0; padding:0; }`

Comment: @PeterKrebs Didn't seem to fix the problem in opera but I tried using chrome and the gaps are no longer there. I really hate browser inconsistancies.

Comment: Yes, that is the price of freedom, everybody wants to create their own browser engine. Be thankful you're not designing E-Mail templates.

Comment: Are you using a high DPI screen with scaling set to other than 100%?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó 1440p with 100% scaling

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Oh I just saw my browser was zoomed to 150%.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sub-Pixels calculated and rendered differently among browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676263/sub-pixels-calculated-and-rendered-differently-among-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes down to inconsistancies between browsers, my browser scaling was set to 150% soo make sure to fiddle arround with that aswell. Ctrl + middle mouse button.

Comment: That does not actually solve the problem, you should consider in mind all the browsers with all the different zoom scalings.